# C++ vkCode/ScanCode to country-specific and case-sensitive character

Tags: c++, windows

I searched in a lot of different places and didn't find any conclusive answer, so I'm asking here.

I have to make a basic Windows keylogger as a school project.

I managed to set it up, and it works quite well. It logs characters and dead keys.

My problem is handling case-sensitive and country-specific input. I can get the SHIFT key state just fine to convert keys into their upper/lowercase equivalent, but I can't actually know what upper/lowercase equivalent it corresponds to.

Example : I'm using a French AZERTY keyboard. Numbers can be written via SHIFT + &, SHIFT + é, etc.

[Here are the results my keylogger displays when trying to log numbers 1 to 5, first via SHIFT + Number and then by using CAPS LOCK.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd56V.png)

If I switch to an English QWERTY keyboard, it will probably work fine, displaying the numbers (but then I'll not be able to access other characters like parentheses).

Is there any way to get a list of all possible keys for a given ScanCode/vkCode, depending on the type of keyboard ?

[Here's a part of my code for the Callback function, and the translation of keys to strings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jipqz.png)

It's the first time I use Windows' C++ API, so I don't really know much about it.

Comment: There are two ways to implement a key logger.  You chose the easy way.  Doing it the *right* way so that ToAsciiEx() always works correctly requires doing it the hard way, a WH_KEYBOARD hook.  Conflicting goals, keep what you have if you want to graduate this year.

Comment: Alright, thanks. WH_KEYBOARD requires a DLL, right ?

Comment: It requires two DLLs, a 32-bit one you can inject into 32-bit processes and a 64-bit one fit for 64-bit processes.  Yes, it is the hard way.